# how can i add a download link with the specific file id in it?

Tags: php, html, mysql, download

How can I add a download link with the specific file id in it.

Here is the code :

```
//loop through results of database query and displaying them in the table 
for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++)
{
    // make sure that PHP doesn't try to show results that don't exist
    if ($i == $total_results)
    {
        break;
    }
    // echo out the contents of each row into a table`
    echo "<tr " . $cls . ">";
    echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'fdesc') . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'category') . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'fdatein') . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="blue-text text-darken-4"><strong>' .   mysql_result($result, $i, 'username') . '</strong></td>';
    echo '<td><a href="d1.php">Download</a></td>';
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: This way of picking away at the results is extremely inefficient and massively verbose. You should just fetch the whole row once and use that data directly.

Comment: i have integrate a paging on it so why i use mysql_query

Comment: I have no idea what that means. It doesn't change the fact that `mysql_query` is dead and you have to stop using it. This isn't up for debate, this was decided by the PHP core team. Whatever you're doing there's absolutely a way to do it with PDO, and you'll probably save yourself a ton of trouble in the process. Plus, as a bonus, this code will work in PHP 7 if you fix that.

Comment: it already work by fetching the result in db but i dont know to pass the id in the download btn to get the file

Comment: You just put the variable in the URL as an argument, or who knows. You don't explain how `d1.php` works.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go Pexter Volcome I rewrote it in mysqli not very differnt at all which is mysql improved so it doesnt have as many security holes in it.

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'pass', 'db');                    
    $sqlpull = $conn->query("SELECT fdesc,category,fdatein,id from table");
    while($row = $sqlpull->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo('<tr '.$cls.">");
        echo('<td>'.$row['fdesc'].'</td>');
        echo('<td>'.$row['category'].'</td>');
        echo('<td>'.$row['fdatein'].'</td>');
        echo('<td class="blue-text text-darken-4"><strong>'.$row['username'].'</strong></td>');
        echo('<td><a href="d1.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Download</a></td>');
        echo('</tr>');
    }
?>
```

When the button gets pressed it will call the php file download all you need is

```
$downloadId = $_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add the code in d1.php for serving the file. The d1.php should first output the correct http content-type header and then output the file contents